# Use Colaboratory with Mac but have excel problem(python)

Tags: python, excel, macos, path, google-colaboratory

I want to read excel but it keep saying that" [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
and my path is copy paste by the document.
does anyone know how to solve this problem ?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

```
df_x_alpha = pd.read_excel('/Users/someone/Desktop/large/excelname.xlsm',sheet_name='Alpha',header = 3,index_col = 2,engine='openpyxl')
df_x_alpha = df_x_alpha.iloc[:,2:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the file in colab thro this(as in image), then without path just give the filename, you can read the excel
[image]